# Invalid user input

Tags: c++

I am having issue with invalid user input. My code opens a file and reads data from a specific date. But one of the dates does not exist in the file, so when a user inputs it, the code goes into an infinite loop. I do not know how to avoid this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    ifstream theFile("Current_Reservoir_Levels.tsv");
    if (theFile.fail()) {
        cerr << "File does not open." << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    string junk;
    getline(theFile, junk);
    string wanteddate;
    string nodate;
    nodate = "12/31/2018";
    cout << "Enter the date you want ";
    if(wanteddate != nodate)
    {
        cin >> wanteddate;
        string date;
        double gallons;
        do {
            theFile >> date;
        }
        while (date.compare(wanteddate) != 0);
        theFile >> gallons;
        
        cout << "East basin storage: " << gallons << endl;
        
        theFile.close();
        
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not handing the case when `theFile >> date` fails when the end of the file is reached.  When that happens, the stream will be put into an error state, and `date` will not receive any more values, which will cause `compare()` to always return a non-zero value, hence your endless loop.

Try something more like this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    ifstream theFile("Current_Reservoir_Levels.tsv");
    if (theFile.fail()) {
        cerr << "File does not open." << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    string junk;
    getline(theFile, junk);
    /* alternatively:
    theFile.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    */

    string wanteddate;
    const string nodate = "12/31/2018";

    cout << "Enter the date you want ";
    cin >> wanteddate;
    if (wanteddate == nodate) {
        return 0;
    }

    string date;
    while (theFile >> date) {
        if (date == wanteddate) {
            double gallons;
            theFile >> gallons;
            cout << "East basin storage: " << gallons << endl;
            return 0;
        }
    }

    cerr << "Date not found." << endl;
    return 1;
}
```